# How to sample 5 index and their probabilities from a tensorflow tensor of probability distribution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a probability distribution (after applying Softmax) where values in each row sums up to 1

```
probs = tf.constant([
    [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
    [0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

I want to sample k index from it and their respective probability values using tensorflow operations.

The expected output for 3 index:

```
index: [
  [4, 3, 4],
  [0, 1, 0]
       ]

probs: [
  [0.4, 0.3, 0.4],
  [0.5, 0.3, 0.5]
       ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a random tensor of indexes with [`tf.random.uniform`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/uniform) :

```
k = 3 # setting up the number of element to sample
# getting the dimension of the prob tensor
row, cols = tf.unstack(tf.shape(probs))
# Generating k values for each row between 0 and cols - 1
idx = tf.random.uniform((row, k), 0, cols, dtype=tf.int32)
>>> idx
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 0, 4],
       [3, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

Using [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) to index the probabilities tensor with the indexes:

```
>>> tf.gather(probs, idx, batch_dims=1)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0. , 0. , 0.4],
       [0. , 0.3, 0.5]], dtype=float32)>
```